# Need to sum values associated with specific words, in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to sum values associated with specific words.  For example, calculate Sum for Food:

```
Column A        Column B 
Food             $8.50 
Food             $5.10 
Maintenance      $12.00 
Laundry          $13.00 
Loan             $1,213.25 
Tution           $100.00
```

The result would be $13.60.

Please let me know which formula I can use

Comment: @eirikdaude: That question seeks to compile the sums for all values in column A, which has different answers than summing for a single value.

Comment: @fixer1234 The question looks identical to me? "I need to look up names from column 1 then sum numbers from column 2" (basically). I.e. do a `SUMIF` for each of the words in column 1. Apart from that it is trivial to find other answers which tells people how to use `SUMIF`, e.g. this one: http://superuser.com/questions/518284/how-can-i-make-a-sum-of-cells-that-match-a-specific-criteria

Comment: @eirikdaude: Good one.  I went ahead and nominated it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUMIF` function as below. You can replace 'Food' with any other word, or preferably a reference to another cell which tells it what word to look for. It looks for the value in column `A`, then sums the corresponding values from `B`.

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,"Food",$B$2:$B$7)`

Comment: Thanks Steve. I used the below formula :  '=SUMIF($A$14:$A$19,Food,$B$14:$B$19)'. But the value is Zero

Comment: You need quote marks around "Food" so it handles it as text, aka a String.